# Rcpp::Environment sodium("package:sodium"); cannot convert to environment

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

When I try to use:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test() {
    Rcpp::Environment sodium("package:sodium");
}
```

The package builds and reloads fine without any error message, but when I call test in R I get:

> error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :    cannot convert to
>   environment

The following works without problem:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test() {
    Environment stats("package:stats"); 
}
```

In R sodium works fine.

Comment: Another option (since it looks like you want to call the individual `sodium` functions from within Rcpp) is to ask Jeroen to modify the package slightly so you can link against it and use the C functions directly and not have to pay the penalty of going to/from the R-level interface for them. It should be a small change for him (from a quick look).

Comment: I think you just need to call `library(sodium)` prior to calling `test`, [as shown here](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/0619f5f667564ed8bff53287514a2e81#file-sodium-test-r). But I agree with @hrbrmstr in that it is much better to call C / C++ functions natively than through an `Environment` object, etc.. At worst, if the author does not wish to provide an interface to the C-level functions, you could just download the source code and modify it locally to do so.

Comment: We **urgently** need an equivalent to `fortunes::fortune(106)` that states how poor this approach is.

Comment: Thank you. I also agree it's better to call C / C++ functions.